# Extract content from each first TD in a Table

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've got some HTML that looks like this:

```
<tr class="row-even">
    <td align="center">abcde</td>
    <td align="center"><a href="deluserconfirm.html?user=abcde"><img src="../images/delete_x.gif" alt="Delete User" border="none" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-odd">
    <td align="center">efgh</td>
    <td align="center"><a href="deluserconfirm.html?user=efgh"><img src="../images/delete_x.gif" alt="Delete User" border="none" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-even">
    <td align="center">ijkl</td>
    <td align="center"><a href="deluserconfirm.html?user=ijkl"><img src="../images/delete_x.gif" alt="Delete User" border="none" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

And I need to retrieve the values, `abcde`, `efgh`, and `ijkl`

This is the regex I'm currently using:

```
preg_match_all('/(<tr class="row-even">|<tr class="row-odd">)<td align="center">(.*)<\/td><\/tr>/xs', $html, $matches);
```

Yes, I'm not very good at them. As with most of my regex attempts, this is not working. Can anyone tell me why?

**Also, I know about html/xml parsers, but it would require a significant code revisit to make that happen. So that's for later. We need to stick with regex for now.**

EDIT: To clarify, I need the values between the first `<td align="center"></td>` tag after either `<tr class="row-even">` or `<tr class="row-odd">`

Comment: I'm not so good with regular expression but could it be that you're missing a portion for the line break between `<tr class...` and `<td align...`?

Comment: please tell us what do you want to do exactly? what is the function of this?

Comment: @JohnoBoy: How do I enter the linebreaks? @klox: I need the values between the first <td align="center"> tag

Comment: You shouldn’t try regular expressions; use a proper HTML parser instead.

Comment: To complete @Gumbo comment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Gumbo: As I've mentioned, I already know that. I'd rather fix this bug now than rewrite entire modules. That task is scheduled for the next release. For now, we need to get this up and running.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Don't sweat it — we're known to be really naggy here :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~<tr class="row-(even|odd)">\s*<td align="center">(.*?)</td>~m
```

Notice the [`m`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier and the use of `\s*`.

Also, you can make the first group non-capturing via `?:`. I.e., `(?:even|odd)` as you're probably not interested in the `class` attribute :)

Comment: Finally! Someone not arguing over regex v/s html parsers! I tried it and it works perfect. Just some clarification please, I tried the \s before and it didn't work with the *. Why is the * needed? Also, what do the ~ characters do?

Comment: In PHP you can use any character to mark the beginning and the end of your regex. He chose `~` for convenience. The `*` is a quantifier. You use it to say that you want between 0 and infinity of a certain class. `\s` in your case, which means space characters.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa What @Alin Purcaru said :) The `~` is chosen since it is not used elsewhere in my pattern. You often see `/` used as delimiter but that would force me to escape it `\/` in the `</td>` part. Regarding `\s`: It will match a space, a tab or a line break (zero-to-many).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:<tr class="row-even">|<tr class="row-odd">).<td align="center">(.*?)<\/td>/s', $html, $matches);
```

Changes made:

- You've not accounted for the newline
  between the tags
- You don't need to x modifier as it
  will discard the space in the regex.
- Make the matching non-greedy by using
  `.*?` in place of `.*`.

[Working link](http://www.ideone.com/PfwHm)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you dont need a too big change in your codebase. Fetching Text Nodes is always the same with DOM and XPath. All that does change is the XPath, so you could wrap the DOM code into a function that replaces your `preg_match_all`. That would be just a tiny change, e.g.

```
include_once "dom.php";
$matches = dom_match_all('//tr/td[1]', $html);
```

where dom.php just contains:

```
// dom.php
function dom_match_all($query, $html, array $matches = array()) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach( $xPath->query($query) as $node ) {
        $matches[] = $node->nodeValue;
    }
    return $matches;
}
```

and would return

```
Array
(
    [0] => abcde
    [1] => efgh
    [2] => ijkl
)
```

But if you want a Regex, use a Regex. I am just giving ideas.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, and it's a valid response except in it's a lot more complicated in my case. I plan on using the simplehtmldom library, which I've found to be pretty slick. This application is for all practical reasons, a crawler. So there are tonnes of regexes spread out throughout the application. Simply including a new library is an effort because there's no central library inclusion class. I'll have multiple copies of code throughout the codebase if I reuse the current architecture. But I see your point, and I'm sure it will help someone looking for a similar solution.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa no problem. You might also be interested in [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662). IMO there is better libraries than SimpleHTMLDom.

Answer (score 0):

This  is just  a quick and dirty regex to meet your needs. It could easily be cleaned up and optimized, but it's a start.

```
<tr[^>]+>[^\n]*\n               #Match the opening <tr> tag
  \s*<td[^>]+>([^<]+)[^\n]+\n   #Group the wanted data
  [^\n]+\n                      #Match next line
</tr>                           #Match closing tag
```

Here is an alternative way, which may be more robust:

```
deluserconfirm.html\?user=([^"]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
<td align="center">([^<]+)</td>
```

I'll explain. One of the challenges here is what's between the  tags could be either the text you're looking for, or an  tag. In the regex the [^<]+ says to match one or more characters that **is not** the < character. That's great, because that means the  won't match, and the the group will only match until the  tag is found.

Comment: Just noticed that in my answer my anchor tags were stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Using regexps to parse HTML is dangerous.

To get the innerhtml of the first TD in each TR, use this regexp:

```
/<tr[^>]*>\s*<td[^>]>(.+?)<\/td>/si
```